# `brew doctor` warnings - are they something to worry about?

Tags: homebrew

I have been using Homebrew for a while and found a problem today while installing Python, probably because I downloaded and installed a `.pkg` file from python's website first, and then run the `brew install python` command as for some reason I found it to be "The right way of doing it" in Python's docs.

Now the `pip` command is running as expected (after restarting my mac), but while trying to found the reason why it was not working I found an answer on SO that was saying to run `brew doctor` to see if there are any problem with Homebrew itself. And there are.

My question is - are there something to worry about?

If yes - can anyone help me how to solve them? Searching for solutions in google gives me some results, but none of them

**First one**

Now gone after commenting a path to mentioned python pkg in `.bash_profile`.

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5m-config
```

**Second one**

```
Warning: You have external commands with conflicting names.

Found command `brew-rmtree` in following places:
  /usr/local/bin/brew-rmtree.rb
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/beeftornado/homebrew-rmtree/cmd/brew-rmtree.rb
```

**Third one**

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

**Fourth one** (all connected with node)

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_build.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_rules.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-barrier.h
  /usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
  /usr/local/include/node/tree.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-os390.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-experimental.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
```

**Fifth one**

This one produces an error included below, while linking.

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python

$ brew link python
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python
$ brew link --overwrite python
```

The last command was run, but still not sure if this was the way to go (the warning from `brew doctor` disappeared though.